# ejabberd how to compile new module

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

[Here](http://www.ejabberd.im/node/2872) I found the code:

```
erlc -I ~/ejabberd-2.1.13/lib/ejabberd-2.1.13/include -pa ~/ejabberd-2.1.13/lib/ejabberd-2.1.13/ebin   mod_my.erl
```

But it did not work?

Comment: Why do you think it didn't work? Did you get an error message?

Answer (score 4):

Here are steps to add your custom module into ejabberd

1. put your module into ejabberd/src folder.
2. come to ejabberd directory in terminal and run command $ sudo make
3. it will show you that your module is compiled. Now run $ sudo make install
4. Add your module into config file at /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml
5. restart your ejabberd and your custom module will be running.

Answer (score 4):

These are the Instructions based on Ejabberd recommendation

1) Form the folder structure like below (refer any module from --
 https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib).

sources
        │
        │───conf
        │         └───modulename.yml
        │───src
        │            └───modulename.erl
        │───README.txt
        │───COPYING
        │───modulename.spec

2) Add your module folder structure to ejabberd user home directory (check ejabberdctl.cfg for CONTRIB_MODULES_PATH param).

3) Type command **ejabberdctl modules_available** it will list your module

4) Type **ejabberdctl module_install module_name** command

For Reference https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/extending-ejabberd/modules/

Answer (score 3):

Just drop the module in the ejabberd's src/ folder then "make". Nothing special needed to compile it.